# Error when using backtracking recursive algorithm to generate maze

Tags: java, recursion, generator, backtracking, maze

I am creating a maze generator using the recursive backtracking algorithm. However, my problem is that every time I run the program it gives the following result:

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

A little background on my code:
The constructor fills the maze int array with 0s, and puts a 1 at the end position (0, 0), and then calls the backtrackGenerateMaze() method to randomly generate a maze. I think the problem may be that I don't have sort of walls, which may be making weird things happen. Also, for the directions: 0 = up, 1 = right, 2 = down, & 3 = left. Hope that helps.

Here's my code (sorry its so long, I've been trying to use comments to debug it):

```
public class Maze {

    private int width, length;
    private int[][] maze;

    public Maze(int rows, int columns) {
        width = columns;
        length = rows;

        maze = new int[rows][columns];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                maze[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        maze[0][0] = 1;

        backtrackGenerateMaze(rows - 1, columns - 1, 1);
    }

    /*
    * THE PROBLEM MUST BE HERE IN THE backtrackGenerateMaze() METHOD
    */
    private void backtrackGenerateMaze(int rows, int columns, int moveLength) {
        if (rows == 0 && columns == 0) {
            System.out.println("rows = " + rows);
            System.out.println("length = " + length);
            System.out.println("columns = " + columns);
            System.out.println("width = " + width);
            return;
        }

        int[] randDirs = generateRandomDirections();

        for (int dir : randDirs) {
            System.out.println("dir == " + dir);
            System.out.println("rows == " + rows);
            System.out.println("columns == " + columns + "\n");
            if (dir == 0) {
                System.out.println("rows - moveLength == " + (rows - moveLength));
                 System.out.println("valid(rows - moveLength, columns) == " + (valid(rows - moveLength, columns)));
                 System.out.println("isInRange(0, length, rows - moveLength, false) == " + (isInRange(0, length, rows - moveLength, false)));

                if (valid(rows - moveLength, columns)
                    && isInRange(0, length, rows - moveLength, false)
                    && maze[rows - moveLength][columns] != 1) {
                    System.out.println("IF 0 is TRUE");
                    for (int i = 1; i <= moveLength; i++) {
                        maze[rows - moveLength][columns] = 1;
                    }
                    maze[rows][columns] = 1;
                    System.out.println("HERE 0");
                    backtrackGenerateMaze(rows - moveLength, columns, moveLength);
                }

                // System.out.println("RETURN DIR 0");
                // return;
            } else if (dir == 1) {
                System.out.println("columns + moveLength = " + (columns + moveLength));
                System.out.println("valid(rows, columns + moveLength) = " + (valid(rows, columns + moveLength)));
                System.out.println();

                if (valid(rows, columns + moveLength)) {
                    System.out.println("VALID 1 is TRUE");
                    if (isInRange(0, width, columns + moveLength, false)) {
                        System.out.println("isInRange() 1 is TRUE");
                        if (maze[rows][columns + moveLength] != 1) {
                            System.out.println("square != 1 is TRUE");
                            System.out.println("IF 1 is TRUE");
                            for (int i = 1; i <= moveLength; i++) {
                                maze[rows][columns + moveLength] = 1;
                            }
                            maze[rows][columns] = 1;
                            System.out.println("HERE 1");
                            backtrackGenerateMaze(rows, columns + moveLength, moveLength);
                        }
                    }
                }

                System.out.println("RETURN DIR 1");
                return;
            } else if (dir == 2) {
                if (valid(rows + moveLength, columns)
                    && isInRange(0, length, rows + moveLength, false)
                    && maze[rows + moveLength][columns] != 1) {
                    System.out.println("IF 2 is TRUE");
                    for (int i = 1; i <= moveLength; i++) {
                        maze[rows + moveLength][columns] = 1;
                    }
                    maze[rows][columns] = 1;
                    System.out.println("HERE 2");
                    backtrackGenerateMaze(rows + moveLength, columns, moveLength);
                }

                System.out.println("RETURN DIR 2");
                return;
            } else if (dir == 3) {
                if (valid(rows, columns - moveLength)
                    && isInRange(0, width, columns - moveLength, false)
                    && maze[rows][columns - moveLength] != 1) {
                    System.out.println("IF 3 is TRUE");
                    for (int i = 1; i <= moveLength; i++) {
                        maze[rows][columns - moveLength] = 1;
                    }
                    maze[rows][columns] = 1;
                    System.out.println("HERE 3");
                    backtrackGenerateMaze(rows + moveLength, columns - moveLength, moveLength);
                }

                System.out.println("RETURN DIR 3");
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------");
    }

    public int[] generateRandomDirections() {
        ArrayList<Integer> rands = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            rands.add(i);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(rands);

        int[] ret = new int[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < rands.size(); i++) {
            ret[i] = rands.get(i);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    private boolean valid(int row, int column) {
        return isInRange(0, maze.length - 1, row, true)
                && isInRange(0, maze[0].length - 1, column, true);
    }

    private boolean isInRange(int start, int end, int toCheck,
            boolean inclusive) {
        if (inclusive) {
            return (toCheck >= start && toCheck <= end);
        }
        return (toCheck > start && toCheck < end);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String ret = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < maze.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < maze[0].length; j++) {
                ret += maze[i][j] + " ";
            }
            ret += "\n";
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

...and here's the Main method I use to run it:

```
public class MazeGame {

    private static ArrayList<Maze> mazes = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final int MAZE_SIZE = 10, NUM_MAZES = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Maze temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_MAZES; i++) {
            temp = new Maze(MAZE_SIZE, MAZE_SIZE);
            System.out.println(temp);
            mazes.add(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try to build a [Short, Self Containd, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: I would if I knew where the problem was...but there's so much code it's hard to trace (especially with the random part).

Comment: Sure, but it's even harder for us!  You have it all set up in your IDE ready to go.  I'm afraid you will have to attack this with the debugger first.

Comment: So what do you suggest I do? I can take parts out if you want...

Comment: Indeed.  Strip out every single line of code that isn't directly relevant to the problem.  If there are code paths that you know aren't taken for your example input, then remove them too (check with an assert statement first to double-check).  Then find the smallest/simplest possible test-case that fails, and see if you can trace through step-by-step to find the iteration that causes divergent behaviour.  You should also use a fixed seed for the random number generation for now, in order to get identical behaviour between multiple runs.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: I'm going to go through and erase all of the irrelevant/unnecessary code/methods/etc. Hopefully that will help.

Comment: @Aubin The expected result is a random maze, where there's a path of 1s and 0s. The 1s are positions that can be "moved onto" and the 0s are the positions that _cannot_ be "moved onto" (that is, when solving the maze, which is not part of my program

Answer (score 0):

This code, runs here, outputs:

```
dir == 2
rows == 9
columns == 9

RETURN DIR 2
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Absolutely not what you said...

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused...Did you run the code I posted, because it should give you the output that I posted...I'm about to remove a lot of code and that should help...thanks for the answer tho :)